# How do I avoid my wife's messages ending up in trash?

Tags: gmail

My wife's e-mail is going from Hotmail to GMail (my account) in the trash account.

How can switch that all her email comes to my inbox GMail account?

Comment: If it's going to Trash and not Spam, more than likely you have a filter that's not doing what you expect. If not, then what third-party tool(s) are you using to work with or manage your Gmail?

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way is to [add her email address to your address book](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9008?hl=en&vid=1-635760109743496468-21970129).

You can use a [Filter](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en) to handle the emails, which will also let you create a subfolder for them.